# How to use final countdown with Meteor/Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

Im trying to user this http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ with my meteor app.

I would like to have feature where user submits a form and then countdown is starting from the second he sends it and I would also need to display the countdown to the user.

Im not sure how exactly I can achieve this what im looking for. 
Im currently doing this in template events:

```
Template.insertProduct.events({
'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    Products.insert({
        name: "randomstring",
        startOfCountdown: new countdown("2016/01/01")
        })
}
});
```

This inserts a row in my "Products" collection:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.products.find()
{ "_id" : "k6eTrs43W3qcJaycn", "name" : "randomstring", "startOfCountdown" : { "
start" : ISODate("2015-04-09T09:53:25.330Z"), "end" : ISODate("2015-04-09T09:53:
25.330Z"), "units" : 222, "value" : 0, "years" : 0, "months" : 0, "days" : 0, "h
ours" : 0, "minutes" : 0, "seconds" : 0 } }
```

But in reality its not helping me much.

I can start the countdown like this if want to test it out, and its working fine.

```
Template.productList.onRendered( function () {
    $('#clock').countdown("2015/04/08", function(event) {
    var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
    $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
    })  
});
```

So my question is - how do I add this jQuery plugin to my collection and display dynamically for every product I insert to my collection? Do I need to add `div id` for every entry in my collection also so the plugin would work?

Thanks alot if anybody bothers to read and think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are conflating the concept of the plugin, whose job is to take a date/time and render HTML / JavaScript that will display a countdown to that date/time, and the collection, whose job is solely to store persistent data.  What you want to do is store any information relevant to the countdown in your collection, then pass that information to the countdown plugin so that it can display the countdown for you.

So, in your collection, you should really only need to store one piece of data; namely, the time you're counting down to:

```
Template.insertProduct.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    Products.insert({
        name: "randomstring",
        endOfCountdown: new Date("2016/01/01")
    });
  }
});
```

From your template names, I'm assuming you have a template called `productList` that is responsible for showing information about several products; I'm guessing it looks something like this...

```
<template name='productList'>
  {{#each products}}
    {{> product}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Then, you have a product template that looks something like...

```
<template name='product'>
  <div class='product'>
    ... <!-- product-related stuff here -->
    <div class='clock'></clock>
  </div>
</template>
```

It's in this template's onRendered that you'll want to add the countdown timer:

```
Template.product.onRendered(function() { 
  Template.instance().$('.clock').countdown(this.data.endOfCountdown, function(event) { // Using Template.instance().$ only searches for instances of .clock in this template instance, not globally
    var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
    $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
  });
});
```

And that will dynamically display the countdown for each individual product.

TL;DR: Separate your concerns re: persistence and display, iterate over templates to display each countdown.

Comment: Thanks alot! its what im after. Altough I get error: Couldn't cast `undefined` to a date object.

Its because of this
 Template.instance().$('.clock').countdown(this.data.endOfCountdown,

It doesnt recognize the data or the format, im not sure which one